# Retrieve Contact info from Android Contact Provider

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contacts, contactscontract

I'm trying to retrieve data from the Contact provider but the data shows seems not query correctly. The code I use is just below:

```
mCursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(
        ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);



if(mCursor == null){
    mListener.onRetrieveError();
    return;
}

for (mCursor.moveToFirst(); !mCursor.isAfterLast(); mCursor.moveToNext()) {
    String contact_f = mCursor.getString(mCursor
            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME));
    String contact_m = mCursor.getString(mCursor
            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.MIDDLE_NAME));
    String contact_l = mCursor.getString(mCursor
            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME));
    String phone_type = mCursor.getString(mCursor
            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE));
    String email_type = mCursor.getString(mCursor
            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE));

    Log.d(TAG,  "|" + contact_l + ", " + contact_f + " " + contact_m + " | " + phone_type + " | " + email_type);
}
```

The Log shows for example :

```
Log: |LastName, FirstName  | FirstName  | FirstName  
Log: |null, 3 null | 3 | 3
```

I was expecting :

```
Log: |LastName, FirstName MiddleName | PhoneType| EmailType
```

I want to be able to get the firstname, lastname, middle name, email type (home/work...) - and all email types listed and also the phone type.

The goal is to for example get for a contact his lastname, firstname middle name and also saying that we got is home and work phone or email

The result I got seems a mix.

Any ideas.

Regards

Comment: Have you tried this tutorial: http://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-details.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not how it works. The [Data](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Data.html) table contains one row per contact value field (phone number, email address, structured name ...). Each row has a [`mimetype`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.DataColumns.html#MIMETYPE) value that tells you how to interpret the columns of that row.

For example, if the `mimetype` column has the value [`Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.html#CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE) you must use the [`Phone`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.html) column mapping to access the data.

So if a contact has one phone number and one email address there are at least 3 rows for this contact in the `Data` table. One for the [`StructuredName`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.html) (this one is required exactly once for each `RawContact`), one for the [`Phone`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.html) number and one for the [`Email`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.html) address.

Each row also has a [`RAW_CONTACT_ID`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.DataColumns.html#RAW_CONTACT_ID) that contains the row id of the [RawContact](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.RawContacts.html) the value belongs to.

When you query the `Data` table, you actually read from a view that joins the real `Data` table with the `RawContacts` table, so each row also contains the [`CONTACT_ID`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.RawContactsColumns.html#CONTACT_ID) of the contact the row belongs to. That means if two rows have the same `CONTACT_ID` they belong to the same contact.

I hope that explains it. I don't really know what you're trying to achieve in the end, so I can't give any helpful code snippets.

#### Update

The key to this is to check the mimetype of each row before you decide how to interpret the values. Also you need to read the `CONTACT_ID` or `RAW_CONTACT_ID` to be able to aggregate the data correctly. If you order the result by `CONTACT_ID` you can assume that all rows belonging to a contact have been read when the `CONTACT_ID` value changes.

The (untested) code snippet below should point you to the right direction. The point is, you can not get all the data of a contact in a single row. You always need to read multiple rows and aggregate them in some way.

```
mCursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(
        ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID);

if(mCursor == null){
    mListener.onRetrieveError();
    return;
}

colIdxContactId = mCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID);
colIdxMimetype = mCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE);

long lastContactId = -1L;

for (mCursor.moveToFirst(); !mCursor.isAfterLast(); mCursor.moveToNext())

  // this is the contact Id the current row belongs to
  long contactId = mCursor.getLong(colIdxContactId);

  if (lastContactId != contactId) {
    // the previous contact is complete, the following data belong to a new contact
    // handle this case ...

    lastContactId = contactId;
  }

  // the mimetype column tells us how to interpret the current row:
  switch(mCursor.getString(colIdxMimetype)) {
    case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE: {
      // this row is a structured name
      String contact_f = mCursor.getString(mCursor
        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME));
      String contact_m = mCursor.getString(mCursor
        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.MIDDLE_NAME));
      String contact_l = mCursor.getString(mCursor
        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME));
      // store names somewhere ...

      break;
    }
    case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE: {
      // this row represents a phone number
      int phone_type = mCursor.getInt(mCursor
        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE));
      // store phone_type somewhere ...

      break;
    }
    case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE: {
      // this row represents an email address
      int email_type = mCursor.getInt(mCursor
        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE));
      // store email_type somewhere ...

      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. What I'm trying to achieve is to extract something like

Comment: Lastname, Firstname, Middle name and also phone numbers + type(home, work, custom..) and same for emails but email data is not where phone data are and where name are (Structured name)

Comment: of all contacts. I do not want the displayed name because I can't make difference between first last and middle name.

Comment: I've added simple example based on your code. It's probably not ideal, but it should give you an idea of how it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
 public void getAllContacts(){


        Cursor cursor = null;
        ContactPerson contact;
        try {
            cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
            int nameIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
            int phoneNumberIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
            int emailAddressIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            do {
                contact = new ContactPerson(cursor.getString(nameIdx),cursor.getString(phoneNumberIdx),cursor.getString(emailAddressIdx));
                cpList.add(contact);
                                    //  Toast.makeText(getActivity(),cursor.getString(nameIdx)+" "+ cursor.getString(phoneNumberIdx),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d("Error",e.getMessage());

        } finally {
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }

   }
```

Comment: this code seems not working. First I need to get First name, last and middle name from the StructuredName and you are querying ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI but email is pointed to CommonDataKinds.Email

Comment: it will give you display name, phone number and email

Answer (score 0):

I think the URI you are using is wrong.
Try using `ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI` instead of `ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI` (this is what I use).

Comment: The issue is that the different info are located at different place. Contacts.CONTENT_URI will give me the Display Name" but the First name, lastname and middle name is located the NamedStructures and you are not using the same query.

Comment: The best for me should be to list all contacts id and be able to send a query with this ID to get details info from this particular ID